# How to fix finalhandler error when running npm install?

Tags: angular, npm

I'am trying to create a new Angular project from scratch running following command:

```
ng new porjectName
```

but I get following error:

```
⠦ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for finalhandler@1.2.0.
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/userName/.npm/_logs/2022-05-03T06_41_07_321Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

The npm, node and angular versions installed on my machine:

```
Angular CLI: 13.1.2
Node: 16.13.1
Package Manager: npm 8.1.2
OS: darwin arm64
```

Any idea, how to fix such error?

Comment: I'd argue from the error message that this Version `@1.2.0` didn't exist, but I looked it up on npm and this package has a version `1.2.0`

Comment: Could you try to install 'finalhandler' globally through npm install and then create project using ng